# Cannot access System Properties (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, security, windows-domain, virtual-memory

In Windows 7, I cannot open

- Advanced system settings (nor "systempropertiesadvanced.exe")
- Computer name, domain and workgroup settings (nor "systempropertiescomputername.exe"
- Performance settings (nor "systempropertiesperformance.exe")

I *can* open System Properties (*the page with the basic information about the system*), but that's where the buck stops.

The combined effect is critical:

- I cannot manipulate pagefile properties (except from the registry)
- I cannot set theme engine global performance options (except from the registry)
- I cannot set prioritisation between foreground and background (except from registry)
- I cannot change computer name, FQDN, Windows workgroup, etc.

### EDIT

Here's some filtered output from Sysinternals' **procmon** (API logger/profiler)

```
23:39:24,4178334    DllHost.exe                     3248    CreateFile  C:\Windows\System32\DllHost.exe.Local                       NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open For Backup, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
23:39:24,5730910    DllHost.exe                     4736    CreateFile  C:\Windows\System32\DllHost.exe.Local                       NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open For Backup, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
23:39:24,6609090    systempropertiesadvanced.exe    816     CreateFile  C:\Windows\System32\systempropertiesadvanced.exe.Local      NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
23:39:30,3618838    DllHost.exe                     5756    CreateFile  C:\Windows\System32\DllHost.exe.Local                       NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open For Backup, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
23:39:30,4175383    DllHost.exe                     5916    CreateFile  C:\Windows\System32\DllHost.exe.Local                       NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open For Backup, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
23:39:30,4369174    SystemPropertiesComputerName.exe5960    CreateFile  C:\Windows\System32\SystemPropertiesComputerName.exe.Local  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
```

Comment: Is the user name you are using a member of the Administrators group?  It needs to be. Can you open an admin Command Prompt?  Then run SFC /SCANNOW, allow it to complete, restart and test.

Comment: @John yes, UAC is setup correctly, so it forces elevation prompts. What does SFC actually do?

Comment: SFC can correct system files that may be damaged or otherwise corrupted

Comment: I am doing it now, but with verifyonly. scannow does automatic repair, which might wreck havoc since it's a destructive op

Comment: @John hi. what do I do with the output

Comment: Look and see if there are errors and then if so look through the very (very) long log to see if anything stands out.  If you ran with verifyonly, then nothing was done, so just review the log. Look near the end of the log.

Comment: I had to filter it using "findstr [SR]". After that, it seems it points me to the custom logon background hack I performed under oobe/background.bmp. Now I have to figure out what I did there....

Comment: For example `2019-10-01 20:06:16, Info                  CSI    00000214 [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:520{260},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32\oobe"\[l:28{14}]"background.bmp"; source file in store is also corrupted`

Comment: See if you can remove what you did there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99360/discussion-between-agnes-k-cathex-and-john).